# Inline content not showing on more than one page

Tags: jquery, jsp, inline, jsp-fragments

I'm facing the following problem:
I'm using `jQuery` to display an `inline pop-up` when trying to press a link on a page. The inline popup is defined inside a `.jspf` page as follows:

```
<div id="x" style="display:none">
    <a id="y" class="thickbox" href="#TB_inline?height=150&width=400&inlineId=w&modal=true">Show hidden modal content.</a>
</div>

<div id="w" style="display: none;">
...
</div>
```

I am using `onclick="checkLogout(); return false;"`  where

```
function checkLogout(){
    document.getElementById("y").click();
}
```

to display the inline content.

The jspf file containing this content is used in multiple jsp files but when clicking the link,
only the first page in a succession of ones using the `jspf` shows the content and behaves normally.
The others call the `checkLogout()` function but don't show the inline content.

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just updated your code in which `<div ....>` was written as `<di v ...>` thinking it was a typo for the question. But could this be the cause of your issue. Please check.

Comment: nope, the original code has <div ...>, i just misspelled it here. sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, it seemed that the java-script sources from the jsp page were not included in the correct order.

The `jquery.js` file needs to be the first js file and only after can you user other `.js` files.

eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="otherJavaScriptFile.js" />
```